# What does 'taxpayer funded' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does 'taxpayer funded' mean?

> Huckfelt says it is important for people to experience the parks.
>   After all, he said, “We own these parks…they’re **taxpayer funded**.”

Article ['Supporting National Parks Through the Arts'](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/supporting-national-parks-through-the-arts/4460605.html) from VOA Learning English.

Comment: In the future, if you're asked to improve a question, please improve it with details and clarifications. Please don't completely change the question, especially if there are answers posted. Also, please provide your research in future posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phrase **taxpayer-funded** means *funded by taxpayers* (people who pay taxes). It's simple as that. I think the fact that it was not properly hyphenated is what threw you off. More generally, the compound adjective *something-funded* means *funded by a specified entity*. Here are a few examples:

> **state-funded** means *funded by the state*
>
> **government-funded** means *funded by the government*
>
> **US-funded** means *funded by the US*

Answer (score 3):

The pattern there is `noun` + `past participle of a VERB`.

The paraphrase is `VERBed by NOUN(s) [sometimes pluralized]`.

> The class elections were student-run.   [run by students]
>
> The medicine was FDA-approved.  [approved by the FDA]
>
> The dog was flea-bitten  [bitten by fleas]
>
> The handle of the tool was rubber-coated.  [coated by rubber]